# How can we output error in Jenkins when using SSH Publishers plugin

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh

i have a shell script in remote server

```
mcccc 1
```

```
$ sh -x demo.sh
+ mcccc 1
demo.sh: line 4: mcccc: command not found
```

in Jenkins project configure page

exec command box of SSH Publishers setting section

```
sh -x demo.sh
```

but in console output of Jenkins, I only get the error below

```
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [127]]
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

how to get "demo.sh: line 4: mcccc: command not found" message

Comment: It would seem the executable `mcccc ` is not in the home directory or is not available in the PATH. expect the SSH is a non-interative shell, so only /etc/profile is sourced, not ~/.bashc or ~/.profile.

Comment: yes, i know, i just want to make the error  message display in Jenkins console output, how to do it